# Magento 2.2.2 deploy specific theme

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, static-content-deploy

I've started to use magento 2.2.2 and I've noticed that running static content deploy for a specific theme (using -t flag) is no more working. All themes are deployed instead of the requested one only. Am I wrong or is a M2.2 issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes,you can do static content deploy to specific theme.

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme {yourTheme}

**Example if you want static content deploy  for luma theme then use**

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Magento/luma

If you want to do static content deploy at **developer/default** mode then `you need to add suffix -f`

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme {yourTheme}  -f

Comment: I never tried with --theme. I always used -t that in M2.1 was perfectly running

Comment: try  it.i  will work

Answer (score 2):

**Static Content Deploy For Magento Backend Theme Using Command Line (Working on 2.1.1 or later)**

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme="Magento/backend"

**Static Content Deploy For Specific Themes Using Command Line (Working on 2.1.1 or later)**

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Magento/luma --theme Magento/second_theme

**Exclude Themes on Static Content Deploy and does not minify HTML files Using Command Line (Working on 2.1.1 or later)**

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US --exclude-theme Magento/luma --no-html-minify

Comment: @DanieleRovatti You can accept answer if it's useful for you. So, other user can use this answer for solve query.